# Update data without manually property setter in DataStore using AWS Amplify with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I used aws-amplify for a very short time for my project. Recently, I'm facing a serious issue about data updating in DataStore in aws-amplify. After reading the docs from their official site I findout that, If I want to update data in DataStore it worked in Immutable way like this,

For creating data,

```
await DataStore.save(
  new Post({
    title: "My First Post",
    rating: 10,
    status: PostStatus.DRAFT
  })
);
```

and for updating data ,

```
const original = await DataStore.query(Post, "123");

await DataStore.save(
  Post.copyOf(original, updated => {
    updated.title = `Any Title`;
  })
);
```

there is no issue with creation but when I goes with update this line is a pain if you have more than 20 property in your object model. Because you have to write all those property and update with it .

```
updated.title = `Any Title`;
```

So, I want to update like this without writing all the property in manually,

```
const updatedTestResult = { ...this.testResult, ...this.testResultForm.value };
var result = await DataStore.save(TestResult.copyOf(this.testResult, updatedTestResult))
```

now it showing me this error,

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
    at datastore.js:376:17
    at produce (immer.esm.js:1:16034)
    at Model.copyOf (datastore.js:375:32)
    at test-result-form.component.ts:130:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32:1
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1427:29)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:21:1
```

or maybe there have another solution. Can you please me on that ?

- TIA

Comment: you can find out github discussion on here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/discussions/9984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally this question is answered in Github discussion. For updating a single property at a time, you could do the following:

```
async function updateTestResult(key, value) {
  try {
    const testResult = await DataStore.save(
      TestResult.copyOf(originalTestResult, (updated) => {
        updated[key] = value;
      })
    );

    console.log("TestResult updated:", testResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Save failed:", error);
  }
}
```

To update multiple properties at once, you could do the following:

```
async function updateTestResult(testResultForm) {
  try {
    const testResult = await DataStore.save(
      TestResult.copyOf(originalTestResult, (updated) => {
        for (const property in testResultForm) {
          updated[property] = testResultForm[property];
        }
      })
    );

    console.log("TestResult updated:", testResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Save failed:", error);
  }
}
```

if you want to see the original ansewer check out this link : https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/discussions/9984#discussioncomment-2959980

Answer (score 0):

I believe, copyOf function takes 2 parameters, 1st one is object and 2nd is callback. so, u can do something like this

```
await DataStore.save(
  Post.copyOf(original, updated => {
    ...updated, ...this.testResultForm.value
  })
);
```

Comment: This is correct - `copyOf` creates a copy of the original value which is immutable. @Sefat you are getting the error because you're trying to make a modification to an immutable data structure. Instead carry over the fields and only modify things which need changing in the update. Please see: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/#create-and-update

Comment: @Suman not working actually, I tried it.

Comment: @Richard I also have array inside it, that's why I don't want to mutate data one by one. I need something dynamic which can responsible to mutate all the changes value and update it in DataStore using the same DataStore update policy.